# Expand navbar items to occupy full width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need to have a navbar with elements to the right, and to the left.

I got this working but the items that are on the left (sign up, login to the left) are not positioned to the most left.

How can I achieve something similar to what this page has?

https://www.stickermule.com/

**Desire result:**

[image]

**What I have:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-bg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">


            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stickers <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Etiquetas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Magnetos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Empaques</a>
                </li>
            </ul>



            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LogIn</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registro</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


    </div>
</nav>
```

**Bonus:**

I'm trying to render a gliphycon icon as a nav item but it doesn't show in navbar. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look at [Bootstrap 4 documentation on navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar) as you used some wrong class names. Check the rest for better understanding of bootstrap features. Bootstrap 4 is different in many ways from Bootstrap 3. You used some classes that don't work in new version. So again: check the docs :)
2. Remember that only 1 `nav-item` element should also have class `active`.

[About the icons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/extend/icons/):

> Bootstrap doesn’t include an icon library by default, but we have a handful of recommendations for you to choose from. While most icon sets include multiple file formats, we prefer SVG implementations for their improved accessibility and vector support.

Here I used [FontAwsome](https://fontawesome.com/icons)

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">


            <ul class="navbar-nav">

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stickers <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Etiquetas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Magnetos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Empaques</a>
                </li>
            </ul>



            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LogIn</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registro</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```